# conjugate function for matrix mixed norm

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, matrix-norms

I am familiar with the conjugate function of the vector norm, which uses the concept of dual norm and is defined as follows:
$$
\|\mathbf{y}\|_p^*
=\max_{\mathbf{x}}\left(\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y}-\|\mathbf{x}\|_p\right)
=\begin{cases}
0, & \text{if } \|\mathbf{y}\|_q\leq 1\\
\infty, & \text{otherwise},
\end{cases}
$$
where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$ for $p\geq 1$.

**My question is:**

Is there an equivalent conjugate function for the mixed matrix norm $\|\mathbf{A}\|_{p,q}=\left(\sum_i \|\mathbf{a}_i\|_p^q\right)^{1/q}$ where $\mathbf{a}_i$ is the $i^{\text{th}}$ column of matrix $\mathbf{A}$?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a duplicate of [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/92996/conjugate-function-for-matrix-mixed-norm/93251#93251) MathOverflow question by the same user, which is answered.